# Why does terraform + apt-get fail, intermittently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apt-get, amazon-ami, terraform

I'm using terraform to create mutiple ec2 nodes on aws:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myapp" {
    count = "${var.count}"
    ami = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type = "m4.large"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.myapp-security-group.id}"]
    subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
    key_name = "${var.key_name}"
    iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.myapp_instance_profile.id}"

    connection {
        user = "ubuntu"
        private_key = "${file("${var.key_file_path}")}"
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "sudo apt-get update",
            "sudo apt-get upgrade -y",
            "sudo apt-get install -f -y openjdk-7-jre-headless git awscli"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run this with say count=4, some nodes intermittently fail with apt-get errors like:

```
aws_instance.myapp.1 (remote-exec): E: Unable to locate package awscli
```

while the other 3 nodes found awscli just fine. Now all nodes are created from the same AMI, use the exact same provisioning commands, why would only some of them fail? The variation could potentially come from:

- Multiple copies of AMIs on amazon, which aren't identical
- Multiple apt-get mirrors which aren't identical

Which is more likely? Any other possibilities I'm missing?
Is there an apt-get "force" type flag I can use that will make the provisioning more repeatable?

The whole point of automating provisioning through scripts is to avoid this kind of variation between nodes :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `remote-exec` provisioner feature of Terraform just generates a shell script that is uploaded to the new instance and runs the commands you specify. Most likely you're actually running into problems with `cloud-init` which is configured to run on standard Ubuntu AMIs, and the provisioner is attempting to run while `cloud-init` is also running, so you're running into a timing/conflict.

You can make your script wait until after `cloud-init` has finished provisioning.  `cloud-init` creates a file in `/var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished`, so you can put this inline with your provisioner:

```
until [[ -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]]; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of `cloud-init` and have it [install arbitrary packages for you](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-arbitrary-packages). You can specify `user-data` for your instance like so in Terraform (modified from your snippet above):

```
resource "aws_instance" "myapp" {
    count = "${var.count}"
    ami = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type = "m4.large"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.myapp-security-group.id}"]
    subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
    key_name = "${var.key_name}"
    iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.myapp_instance_profile.id}"

    user_data = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered}"
}

# Standard cloud-init stuff
data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
    # I've 
    gzip = false
    base64_encode = false

    part {
        content_type = "text/cloud-config"
        content = <<EOF
packages:
    - awscli
    - git
    - openjdk-7-headless
EOF
    }
}
```